# How to connect with iwconfig using ASCII passphrase

Tags: iwconfig

I'm trying to connect to a network with an ASCII passphrase of 9 characters.

I give the network key as

```
iwconfig eth1 key s:abcdefghi
iwconfig eth1 essid "My Network"
```

It gives an error as:

```
AP(BSS) finding:Found a AP(BSS)..
802.11 Authen (OPEN) Failed.
Status code == Unspecified error.
WLAN_AUTHENTICATE_WAIT:Authen Fail???
```

How should I enter the passphrase?